# Why does foreach operator fail with NullPointerException when using Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my function:

```
def TestForeach(dataFrame: DataFrame)={
  dataFrame.select("user_id").dropDuplicates().foreach(row =>{
  dataFrame.filter("user_id == "+row.getString(0))
  })
}
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 16)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1318)
```

How to get Dataframes with the same user_id?

Comment: Could you include the exception to the question please? That would make it more complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` executes the action on executors while `dataFrame` is available on the driver only.

You should `collect` before `foreach`. With the change, `foreach` is then Scala's not Spark's `foreach`.

Comment: This helped me on another equivalent problem. @jacek-laskowski would you like to elaborate a bit on why is it necessary?

Comment: What exactly is not clear? I'm here to help ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dataFrames within a transformation or action. You need to collect your user-ids first:

```
def testForeach(dataFrame: DataFrame): Seq[DataFrame] = {
  val userIds: Array[String] = dataFrame.select("user_id").distinct.map(_.getString(0)).collect
  userIds.map(uid => dataFrame.filter($"user_id" === uid)).toSeq
}
```